# Usar puntuación extra para expresar incredulidad

Tags: gramática, puntuación

En inglés a veces, se usa puntuación extra para indicar confusión o ira en una frase, como en:

> He said *what*??
>   Are you serious?!

etc.

Porque se pone ciertos tipos de puntuación al principio y al final de la frase en español, ¿cómo se escriben estas frases en español?

¿Son estas correctas?

> ¿¿Él dijo *qué*?? (¿o, "¿Él dijo *qué*??", tal vez?)
>   ¡¿Hablas en serio?! (...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las frases que has escrito son correctas en cuanto a los signos de puntuación (te sobra el pronombre "lo" en la primera, y en cuanto a la segunda, la traducción sería "¿¡Hablas en serio!?" o "¡¿Lo dices en serio?!"). También puede iniciarse con un signo y terminar con el otro:

> ¿Él dijo qué!

o

> ¡Él dijo qué?

Estos dos ejemplos son estrictamente correctos aunque la RAE recomienda usar los dos, como tú has utilizado, en cualquier orden, y así es como yo los he visto siempre.

Siempre que utilices más de un signo para empezar la frase, debes terminar con el mismo número de signos, y siempre en el orden inverso (el signo que abre es el que cierra).

Origen: http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=interrogaci%F3n%20y%20exclamaci%F3n%20(signos%20de)

Comment: ¡Gracias por sus correcciones!  Voy a editar mi pregunta.

Comment: Personalmente pienso que, de los dos casos expuestos con signos mixtos, es más útil abrir un signo de exclamación y cerrar un signo de interrogación. La razón es que la entonación del español indica interrogación hacia el final de la frase.

Comment: @Alpha Eso es un punto excelente, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una pregunta muy común cuando alguien ve preguntas o exclamaciones en español por primera vez. Esa es simplemente la forma como se escribe, asi es la regla, se debe de poner el signo de puntuación al principio y al final tanto en preguntas como en exclamaciones.

Entonces si deseas crear un efecto de confusión o sorpresa al escribir y escribes ambos tipos de signos, debes de escribirlos también al principio como lo hiciste.